# kendo dropdrownlist not getting fired on change() function

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui

Im using kend dropdownlist .im loading the datas from json . onchange of dropdownlist event is not getting fired

```
 <input class="ddEmailInitiation" />
 <script>$(".ddEmailInitiation").kendoDropDownList
  ({
     dataTextField: "Type",
     dataSource: json,
     change: function () { alert('change') }
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to set `dataValueField`.

> When dataTextField is defined, the dataValueField option also should
>   be set.

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#configuration-dataTextField